# Frequency count all words in a single column in a a table using php

Tags: php, mysql

```
id | words                            | other
1  | lorem ipsum                      | dsf
2  | Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy      | sads
```

given this table now  I want a query in php that will give me frequency count in the entire words column

Expected Output of this should be-

```
loreum-2
ipsum-2
is-1
simply-1
dummy-1
```

P.s.-I am passing the data as a whole 
using-

```
$array = array($word);
print_r(array_count_values($array));
```

it is giving me the output

```
lorem ipsum -1
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy-1
```

Please help me out I'm pretty much new to this.

Comment: Show the code that you've written to do the (wrong) count you're getting, please.

Comment: its up there " $array = array($word);
print_r(array_count_values($array)); "

Answer (score 1):

```
$words = explode(' ',$word);
$result = array();
foreach($words as $w){
  $result[$w]++;
}
print_r($result);
```

considering that you will have to iterate on each row of the database result to check for each word. The algorithm above is for one phrase or one row only, modify to suit your needs. I don't know if you have to consolidate all the words or you have to get the count of each word for each row.

Answer (score 1):

This is the gist of what I would do...  I'm just going to explain the idea around it rather than give straight code.

The goal would be to create an array, say N, that has a series of keys each corresponding to one of the words, and the value of each key corresponding to the number of occurrences of that key (word).

For each row in the database table,

Explode the words column using space as the delimeter to create an array X.

For each word in X,

Check if the key exists in N, if key does not exists create it and set its value to 1, otherwise increment its current value by 1

Now you have N fully populated with what you want.